# HBase- Duplicate Values When Adding Column

Tags: hbase, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to store some location (latitude,longitude) values in HBase. I decided to add a column each time I have a new value from my HashMap of key and value pairs. My HashMap is like following:

**{lat:43.7719802, lon:-79.5008048}** *(A sample JSon representation of Hashmap)*

And here is my code:

```
HTable table = new HTable(hBaseConfig, TableName);    
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : Columns.entrySet()) {
                    Append a = new Append(rowKey);
                    a.add(Bytes.toBytes("a"), Bytes.toBytes(entry.getKey()), Bytes.toBytes(entry.getValue()));
                    table.append(a);
    }
```

But When I want to retrieve values, They are stored redundant. I mean they are glued together in one cell mutiple times for each value, like this: -79.5008048-79.5008048-79.5008048

I'm using HBase 0.94.15-cdh4.7.0 library in my code.

Does anybody know a clue for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are accumulating in the cells because you asked them to: you are using the `append` method.

Try `put` to overwrite instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems that when the column exists, Append accumulate the contents. I did a "get" before "append"ing each column for this issue. But How can I use "put"? I don't want to overwrite anything in the row. I just want to add bunch of columns to it.

Comment: Like append, put can operate on individual cells in a row.  Putting one cell in a row does not have any effect on other cells in the row.